# SQL Server : Split Columns to Count Totals By Year in same row

Tags: sql, t-sql, split, ssms

T-SQL question: I have a breakdown of the visits by year of a person. I want to get a count of the total visits per year and then create a column for each year to summarize the total. The way I have it now it only returns the totals per year for the columns on separate rows. How can I combine them?

Example temp table and code...

```
CREATE TABLE #Events            
(
     Col1 int PRIMARY KEY,
     Person Varchar(20),
     VisitYear INT,
     VisitInfo Varchar(20)
)           

INSERT INTO #Events 
VALUES (1, 'User1', '2017', 'Combo'), (2, 'User1', '2017', 'Special'),
       (3, 'User1', '2018', 'ComboBig'), (4, 'User2', '2017', 'Special'),
       (5, 'User2', '2017', 'ComboBig'), (6, 'User2', '2018', 'ComboBig'),
       (7, 'User2', '2018', 'Special'), (8, 'User2', '2018', 'Special2'),
       (9, 'User3', '2018', 'Combo')            

SELECT DISTINCT 
    Person,
    VisitYear,
    VisitInfo,
    COUNT(Person) OVER(PARTITION BY Person, VisitYear) AS TtlPerYear 
INTO 
    #EventCountPerYear
FROM 
    #Events E

SELECT * 
FROM #EventCountPerYear

SELECT DISTINCT 
    E1.Person,
    CASE WHEN E1.VisitYear IN ('2017') THEN E1.TtlPerYear END AS '2017_Visits',
    CASE WHEN E1.VisitYear IN ('2018') THEN E1.TtlPerYear END AS '2018_Visits'
FROM 
    #EventCountPerYear E1
```

Right now the results comes split with the Year counts on separate rows. Is there a way to have it result in just one clean row of data?

Images of current and desired results listed below...

The current results:

[image]

Desired results]

[image]

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SQL-Server you could use a PIVOT:

> ```
> SELECT Person, [2017], [2018]
> FROM (SELECT Person, VisitYear FROM #Events) src
> PIVOT (COUNT(VisitYear) FOR VisitYear IN ([2017],[2018])) pvt
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Person | 2017 | 2018
> :----- | ---: | ---:
> User1  |    2 |    1
> User2  |    2 |    3
> User3  |    0 |    1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a69e3909990654a7b5828ceae9be86ba)*

Answer (score 0):

You are on the path to using conditional aggregation.  This looks like:

```
SELECT E1.Person
       SUM(CASE WHEN E1.VisitYear IN (2017) THEN E1.TtlPerYear END) AS [2017_Visits],
       SUM(CASE WHEN E1.VisitYear IN (2018) THEN E1.TtlPerYear END) AS [2018_Visits]
FROM #EventCountPerYear E1
GROUP BY E1.Person;
```

Notes:

- Don't put single quotes around numeric values, such as the year.
- Don't use single quotes for column aliases.  In fact, only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- This adds the `GROUP BY` clause.